# Multi Map to JSON using java

Tags: java, json

From my result set i have the data as below

My multi map is returning me
multiMap:`{aaa=[78, 3], bbb=[84, 39], ccc=[74, 41]}`

i want to add the above data to json as given below:

```
name:aaa
data:[78,3]
name:bba
data:[84, 39]
```

can you help me in this

Answer (score -2):

Use Gson library provided by **[Google](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)**.

```
public static String getString(final Object object) {  
      Gson gson = new Gson();  
      return gson.toJson(object);  
}
```

In this method you simply pass your object it will return you JSON String.

Link: [JSON to java and Java to JGON](http://iandjava.blogspot.in/2014/01/java-object-to-json-and-json-to-java.html)

Comment: i want to add the key to an attribute and value to other attribute .how is it possible?

Comment: Now if my string is{"aaa":["78","3"],"bbb":["84","39"],"ccc":["74","41"]}how will i save to name:aaa,data["78,3"] and so on

Comment: a guava multimap can't directly be converted using gson, you need to call multimap.asMap first and serialize that.

Comment: Don't help, as it can't be directly converted in json.